# How do I use transactions with Stomp and ActiveMQ (and Perl)?

Tags: perl, activemq-classic, stomp

I'm trying to replace some bespoke message queues with ActiveMQ, and I need to talk to them (a lot) from Perl.  ActiveMQ provides a Stomp interface and Perl has Net::Stomp, so this seems like it should be fine, but it's not.

Even if I send a `BEGIN` frame over Stomp the messages sent with `SEND` are immediately published, and if I `ABORT` the transaction nothing happens.

I can't find any clear answers suggesting that it's not possible, that it is possible, or that there's a relevant bit of configuration.  Also, Stomp doesn't seem to be a great protocol for checking for error responses from the server.

Am I out of luck?

Answer (score 3):

BTW the best place to ask Perl/ActiveMQ/Stomp questions is the [ActiveMQ user forum](http://activemq.apache.org/discussion-forums.html) as lots of Perl-Stomp folks hang out there.

The trick with STOMP transactions is to make sure each message you send or each acknowledgement you make includes the transaction ID header. See the [transaction handling section of the STOMP protocol](http://stomp.codehaus.org/Transaction+Handling).

The reason for this is that with STOMP you could have many transactions taking place at the same time if your client is multi threaded - along with some non-transacted operations.

Comment: Yeah, I'm following the Stomp protocol rules and sending a transaction header.  (I wish I could get tcpflow working on this machine; tcpdump sucks for watching stomp.)  I'll try that forum, too, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Net::Stomp::Receipt](http://search.cpan.org/~huguei/Net-Stomp-Receipt-0.34/lib/Net/Stomp/Receipt.pm). It's a subclass of Net::Stomp that implements "return receipts" from the Stomp protocol, and allow you to make sure the correct reception of your message, and abort the transaction otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap the acknowledgements inside a transaction.

In pseudocode (or pseudo STOMP) this would be:

- BEGIN [TRANSACTION-ID] -> send to server
- MESSAGE [MESSAGE-ID] (received) <- received from server
- ACK [MESSAGE-ID] [TRANSACTION-ID] -> send to server
- COMMIT [TRANSACTION-ID] -> send to server

I have already gotten this working with the PHP driver (patching the abort call to use the transaction ID when I pass in a frame object to acknowledge).

Unfortunately, after redelivering four messages the client stops. At least this happens to me.

Comment: if say, I have a while loop, would that pseudo code be in the loop? or would BEGIN and ABORT be outside ?

Comment: They would be inside the loop since you need to open a transaction for each message sent and received.

Comment: would the transaction-id be set to something different every time?

Comment: Using COMMIT instead of ABORT changes everything. Instead of flagging an error and re-queuing the message it would remove it.

Comment: The transaction identifier must be included, must be unique for each open transaction and must be generated by the client or consumer.